# Conform to protocol?

Tags: swift2

Using Swift 2.0 I have a problem conforming to a protocol.
I broke down the code as much as possible to illustrate the issue.

```
protocol Filter {
    var filterName:BaseModel {get}
}

protocol BaseModel {
    var name: String {get}
}

enum SomeModel: BaseModel {
    case Something
    var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .Something:
            return "yeah"
        }
    }
}

struct SomeFilter:Filter {

    var filterName:SomeModel
}
```

With this code I get:

> Type 'SomeFilter' does not conform to protocol 'Filter'

Since SomeModel is of type BaseModel (conforms to BaseModel) this should work. If I change change `var filterName:SomeModel` to `var filterName:BaseModel` in SomeFilter it works of course, but I can't figure out why it does not see SomeModel as a BaseModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `var filterName: SomeModel` is not what the protocol is saying.

You might try something like this with generics to accomplish your idea.

```
protocol Filter {

    typealias BaseModelType
    var filterName: BaseModelType { get }
}

protocol BaseModel {

    var name: String { get }
}

enum Model: BaseModel {

    case A
    case B

    var name: String {

        switch self {
        case .A:
            return "hello world"
        case .B:
            return "bye world"
        }
    }
}

struct SomeFilter<T: BaseModel>: Filter {

    typealias BaseModelType = T
    var filterName: BaseModelType

    init(filterName: BaseModelType) {

        self.filterName = filterName
    }
}

let test = SomeFilter(filterName: Model.A)

test.filterName.name // prints "hello world"
```

I hope this might help you somehow. Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: Thanks for this! I didn't actually know about generics in Swift until now. I ended up with a slightly different solution which was actually better, but at least I learned something.

Comment: Sure :) There is never the true one and only solution, this is what I like about programming, solving the puzzle with different pieces.

Comment: @r0yalty If you found a better solution please answer your own question and mark it as answered. So other programmers also benefit.

Answer (score 0):

So basically I realised I didn't need to create custom filters, just custom Models and ended up with something like this.

```
protocol Model {
    var name:String {get}
}

struct Filter {
    var model:Model
}


enum SpecificModel: String, Model {
    case Something, SomethingElse

    var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .Something:
            return "something"
        default:
            return rawValue
        }
    }
}
```